# Check Box adding 2 entries to Payload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've the following in ruby file html.erb

```
<div class="hidden" id="contractor-group"> 
   <%= f.check_box :contractor, id: 'int_contractor_check'%>
   <label for="contractor">Internal Contractor</label>
</div>

function enableContractor() {
  var type = $('#company-type').val();
  if (type == 'INTERNAL') {
     $('#contractor-group').removeClass('hidden')
     $('#int_contractor_check').prop('checked', false);
  }
  else {
     $('#int_contractor_check').prop('checked', false);
     $('#contractor-group').addClass('hidden')
  }
}
```

A dropdown change to INTERNAL toggles the checkbox hidden/shown

```
id: "company-type",
onchange: "enableContractor()",
```

In the payload I get double contractor entries. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong here. For checkboxes Rails creates a hidden field with `0` value (you can check it in generated html). It's needed b/c checkbox value is send only when checkbox is checked.
So, to avoid having nothing send, when it's not checked, we need this hidden input. When parsing it on the server, Rails will overwrite `0` with the latest value (`1`)
See [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

Answer (score 0):

I stripped down the code to the following and it's working fine now. Using `true` and `false` was better to use on server side anyway. Not sure why the server wasn't using the value 1 ever,

Thanks @faron for the link, something I didn't know.

```
<div class="hidden" id="contractor-group">
   <%= f.check_box :contractor, { checked: false }, true, false %>
    <b> Internal Contractor </b>
</div>
```